# Can we do an inversion of a function when taking probability?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $F(x) = \Pr[X\leq x]$ and $Y$ be some function of $X$ such that $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ can be inverted $X=g^{-1}(Y)$. We need to find
$$
\Pr[Y\leq c],
$$
where $c$ is some constant.  Can we do the following:
$$\Pr[g(X)\leq c] = \Pr[X\leq g^{-1}(c)]?$$

Comment: The approach is correct but you have to take care of the inequality sign depending on the nature of the function (increasing/decreasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality will hold if $g(X)\leq c$ is equivalent to $X\leq g^{-1}(c)$. That's not true for every bijection (e.g. $x\mapsto -x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ does not satisfy this) but it's true for a strictly increasing one.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on $g$. For example, if $g(x) = -x$, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y \leq c) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq -c) \neq \mathbb{P}(X \leq -c)
$$
Moreover, $g^{-1}(x)$ should be well-defined for all values the variable $X$ can take.